# Printing specific items in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a newbie and trying to do this for my college class.
I have created an array called birds:
Here is my code:

```
<?php // This script creates an array called birds and then prints out the birds 1-3 and then prints the birds 0,, 2 and 4
$birds = array ("Whip-poor-will|Chickadee|Pileated Woodpecker|Blue Jay|Rufus-sided Towhee|Scarlet Tanager");
```

I need to print out specific items within the array using foreach.
would the next code be

```
Foreach($birds as $key =>value){print "$key $1,2,3 <br>";}
```

Answer (score 4):

The array needs to be initialized with this syntax:

```
$birds = array(
    "Whip-poor-will", 
    "Chickadee", 
    "Pileated Woodpecker", 
    "Blue Jay", 
    "Rufus-sided Townee", 
    "Scarlet Tanager");
```

And the `foreach` would be:

```
foreach($birds as $key => $value)
{
  echo "$key - $value<br/>";
}
```

If you wanted to get data for specific elements of the array, they are referenced by index:

```
echo $birds[0];
//output will be: Whip-poor-will

echo $birds[2];
//output will be: Pileated Woodpecker
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit too picky, perhaps, but it's actually `<br />` (with a space). At least in XHTML standard code.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! I finished that one and on to learning other new stuff.  Multi dimensional arrays! sounds like fun :-) well maybe LOL